# Why are my python3 pip modules installed in two different directories

Tags: python, pip

I don't understand why using the same command, some python3 pip modules have been install in two different locations :

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3 -V
pip 19.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
$ sudo -H /usr/local/bin/pip3 install pychromecast | grep /usr/local/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied: pychromecast in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pychromecast) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zeroconf>=0.17.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pychromecast) (0.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: casttube>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pychromecast) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from protobuf>=3.0.0->pychromecast) (41.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from protobuf>=3.0.0->pychromecast) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ifaddr in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from zeroconf>=0.17.7->pychromecast) (0.1.6)
$ sudo -H /usr/local/bin/pip3 install pychromecast | grep /usr/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pychromecast) (2.2.1)
```

EDIT0 : My `sys.path` :

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

EDIT1 : @furas You are right, I just found out that both `python-requests` and `python3-requests` Ubuntu packages are installed on my system.
But then, I can't uninstall them because many much other ubuntu packages depend on them.

<s>If anyone understands why, please let know :-)</s>

EDIT2 : Please note that I do NOT want `/usr/local/bin/pip3` to touch the system `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` directory.

I just wanted to make sure that the packages that I install via `/usr/local/bin/pip3` will always be installed into the `/usr/local/lib/python3.6` or `/usr/local/lib/python3.`

Comment: What's your `import sys; print(sys.path)` when you run the python 3.6 REPL?

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski `['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Comment: The last item explains it. Something is adding `/usr/lib/python3/` to the path. Check all your environment variables, especially`PYTHONPATH`, `PATH`, `PYTHONSTARTUP`

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski `env | grep python3` shows nothing and your `strace ...` command does not show any environment variable either. It's 4AM (in France), I have to go to bed. I'll check the other suggestions tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far. Cheers :)

Comment: did you install `requests` with `pip` ? Some modules can be installed with `apt` (Debian/Ubuntu) and they may have defined one folder for all versions 3.x - 3.5, 3.6, 3.7. All can depends on Linux distribution. But I wouldn't bother this.

Comment: @furas See my EDIT1

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski See my EDIT1

Comment: @SebMa Can you run `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ | grep link`?

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ | grep link | wc -l` prints `0`

Comment: I checked `sys.path` in my 3.6 and 3.7 and both have `'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'` on the list. And all works without problems for many years. As I remember `/usr/lib/` is used for libraries used by system, and Ubuntu could install some Python's modules here because Ubuntu uses Python to run some elements in system. And it could install `requests` here when Ubuntu is installed on disk. So stop changing this. Do you have problem to run modules in Python ? If not then stop bother this.

Comment: I also found that I have `requests 2.19` in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'` but I have also `requests 2.21` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'` - probably because I use `sudo pip3.6 install --upgrade requests` from time to time. Because `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'` is before ``/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages' so when I use `requests` in script then it use newer version `2.21`

Comment: if you use `pip --user` then you install modules in local folder `~/.local` and then you will have modules installed in three different folders ;)

Comment: @furas See my EDIT0 and my EDIT2 paragraphs.

Comment: @furas I believe my config. is fine. I just needed to understand what the `sys.path` was.

Comment: `sys.path` is list of all folders where Python is looking for modules when you import them. And it doesn't matter if module goes to one of another folder. If this folder is in `sys.path` the Python will import this module.

Comment: I use Python on Linux for many years and I don't care where modules are installed. And I never had problem with `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. I think this folder can be used by `apt` to install modules created by Ubuntu.